# How to create an object of any class that is available in the solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-2.0

I have a serious question for you guys. I am working on a project that has hundreds of classes. Why cant i access all classes if i want to create an object of that class.

For example: I have Class A, B and C.

In Page 1, i can create an object of A and B but not C. When i try to type in Class C, the intellisense does not work. I need to access class C to get some of the functions used in it.
What can i do to get access to create objects of class C??

Comment: It's because the class is named "C". Change the name to "D" and it will work.

Comment: @John Saunders ~ The levity is appreciated but probably misunderstood ... Also, @Ram ~ PLEASE ~ PLEASE ~ PLEASE give us some sample code. I imagine that classes A and B are declared differently than C ... or they are in a different namespace

Comment: @drach: sorry, it's better than what I was originally going to say. The word "benighted" might have been used.

Comment: @drach: besides, if he had tried my suggestion, it would have failed, and he might then have decided to **POST SOME CODE**

Comment: @Ram: if you were going to ask for help from a colleague, maybe one who is almost as new as you, what would you do first? You would show them the code. Please do the same for us.

Comment: @John Saunders ~ lol, too funny. I like that ... `benighted` ... gotta remember to use that word more often ... 'course my regular crowd gets tired of the use of $.50 words ... ah well ;)

Comment: @drach: I like the second definition at http://encarta.msn.com/dictionary_1861589997/benighted.html. It makes me think of someone at night, walking from one village to another, but night came while still between villages. No lights, no clues, wild animals howling in the woods, kind of lost and pathetic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chances are you're missing either:

- An assembly reference (to the project containing class C)
- A `using` directive for the *namespace* containing class C

For example, to use the `NetworkStream` class, you'd need a reference to the System.dll assembly, and you'd usually have a using directive like this:

```
using System.Net.Sockets;
```

in the class that needed to use it. You don't *have* to have a `using` directive - you can specify the full name explicitly - but it's usually a good idea.

Now it's also possible that class C is *internal* to the project it's part of, and you're in a different project - which means that you don't have access to it (and you're not meant to). Or perhaps you're trying to call a constructor and there aren't any publicly available ones, for example.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a namespace issue.  You can put classes into unique namespaces to avoid naming conflicts between classes and also to help organize your code.  Take a look at each class and determine what namespace it resides in.  If they reside in different namespaces you will have to put a using statement at the top of the class your trying to access them from.  Also if some of the class reside in physical different projects you will have to reference them as well.  Hope this helps.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely class C doesn't exist within the same assembly or namespace as the other classes. Double check your references and using statements and you will likely find class C will become available to you.